Using HP ProCurve 1810G - 24 GE as ONT
We will get fiber internet and now I am wondering if I really need the ONT-Modem.
My Idea would be connect the fiber to the Switch and then forward it to the WAN Port of the router.
Is this possible?
If yes I suppose it's not possible to connect the Fiber in the Fiber Port 24 and the LAN cable to the router in the Copper Port 24?
I suppose I need to make an VLAN and use two different Ports for that?
Sorry, until now I only used the switch dumb and I don't know what I do^^

That depends.
Most likely, the ONT links to a passive optical network (PON) where the uplink is shared with adjacent ONTs and data is multiplexed using time slots (TDM). An 1810G switch doesn't support that kind of link, so it can't be used.
If the network is an active one, you'd need to find out the wavelength(s) and link speed to match the transceiver type. A single-fiber (simplex) link uses WDD to split uplink and downlink - 1000BASE-BX10-U with 1490/1310 nm would be a common variant for 1 Gbit/s. J9143B would be the HPE part for that, but it's not listed as compatible for the 1810 series.
A duplex fiber link might use the more common 1000BASE-LX variant, and that one you could connect to the 1810 using a J4859C or compatible transceiver.
If you succeed, just make sure that you configure a dedicated VLAN for fiber-to-Ethernet adaptation towards your router. You'd configure those two ports untagged for just that VLAN and no tagged VLANs.
